# WaoN - WAV to MIDI conversion

Tags: audio, wav, midi

I've been wanting to learn more about WaoN, since using it for a little and I can't seem to find much about how it does the conversion from WAV to MIDI. I tried looking at the main code of the program but I can't understand it as it is extensive and confusing.

Are there any links to explanation about WaoN and how it works? Or how does WaoN convert a WAV file to MIDI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to analyze an audio signal to estimate its pitch.

A technique often found in guitar tuners is autocorrelation, a time-domain technique which is the process of correlating the signal with a delayed copy of itself in an attempt to find repeated patterns (such as the period of a sound). For more advanced analysis such as accurate detection of polyphonic content, FFT is often applied to do analysis in the frequency-domain. It's a more computationally demanding process but often gives more accurate results and flexibility in analysis.

Admittedly, I have only had a shallow look at the WaoN source, but its using such a frequency-domain method. It's applying FFT to get the spectrum of the audio, then some processing to subtract drums or noisy content, and finally looking for specific frequency peaks that exceed the average power of the spectrum - These can be identified as notes.

If you're interested to learn more about pitch detection algorithms, Wikipedia provides a decent overview (specifically the section on frequency-domain approaches):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm

For more in-depth look at the FFT approach for extracting pitch, Bjorn Roche has done a good write-up on the subject: 
http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html